# Add sidebar menu in Windows Phone application like Facebook app

Tags: windows

i am new to window Application development , i have to create slide bar menu like facebook in my App .

I go through [this link](http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.in/2013/08/add-lateral-menus-to-windows-phone.html).

But it does not works for me.

Comment: Please be more clear when asking questions. What does not work. Is there things you have tried to fix the problem. Is there things that you have done differently from the sample. etc.

Comment: it works now , i sort out my error ........thanks alot,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code :

https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=68f2640a052556e2&id=68F2640A052556E2%2122184

i am able  to implement it using an templated panorama or pivots.

Then i use :

I have a canvas/grid that has a width of 1320 and the height stretches to the whole available height that contains my whole view

The view is inserted in a canvas with initial Canvas.Left position set to -420 this way we see the main view port (component)

The "stable" positions inside the canvas are:  0: left menu opened, -420: main view and -840:right menu opened

When pressing the buttons we will use a resource Storyboard with a  DoubleAnimation to set the the Canvas.Left position inside the canvas to 0,-420 or -840: